# UINavigationController and Grandchild Views XCode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've got a UINavigationController in my storyboard, and when I go to add additional UIViewControllers, they do not seem to inherit the navigation bar. I then add a navigation bar control, but it doesn't match the default one in its parent--it's height is different and doesn't go under the battery icon.

I feel like I'm missing something simple for my workflow.

Edit: I forgot to mention I am using the Present Modally segue. If I use Show (e.g. Push) it gives me the navigation bar. I'd prefer to use Present Modally and have the navigation bar so I can present Save/Cancel buttons. But I want the bar to look exactly like its parent's navigation bar.

Edit 2: Added screenshot to show the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the presented view controller in its own navigation controller. View controllers only share a navigation controller when you push the additional view controllers onto the existing navigation controller. When presenting modally, the navigation controller is not shared. That's the point of presenting modally - to add a new stack.

Comment: That's good to know about the additional navigation controllers. Do you know how I can get the additional navigation bar that I added to my Modal to make its height as tall as the parent controller? I'd rather minimize the number of story boards, given that navigation controllers come with two screens. Does that make sense?

Comment: Don't add a nav bar. Just put the view controller in its own navigation controller and present the new navigation controller.